# How to copy Wordpress live website to Bitnami stack localhost?

Tags: migration, local-installation

I just started trying Bitnami WordPress but don't know how to copy my live website to localhost.

I have downloaded files from my website from **sFTP** server and also downloaded database file from `wpengine`. Thank you.

If it's not possible, can someone please recommend me the best localhost environment which doesn't give trouble? I was using **MAMP** and **XAMPP** but there's always some problem with the apache server or disabled or stopped PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same procedure as going from local to live website.

Supposing that you are using a Windows Machine, when downloading a Bitnami Wordpress Installer, it creates a folder in C directory and than you can overwrite all the files with the downloaded ones ***execpt wp-config.php***,
After the phpMyAdmin installation where you must import the downloaded database and change the address URL of the website to the local one.

First step: Delete the generated database from the Bitnami Wordpress Installer

Second step: Import the downloaded database from wpengine.

Third step:Login to your MySQL manager (likely phpMyAdmin) and edit the entries for

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

Under the wp_options table.

```
http://example.com  **to:** 
http://localhost/wordpress/:81 (The port number is optional)
```

Giving a personal recommendation regarding a local environment I would suggest working on a Linux virtual machine.

Try installing an Ubuntu OS and a LAMP stack on it.

For reference:

Installing LAMP Stack https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Installing Wordpress https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04